# How to get NIC to work at 1000mbps

Tags: networking, dual-boot

My Acer AXC-603 is set up to dual boot Ubuntu 15.04 and Win 8.1.  My ISP is Comcast with internet download speed "Blast" (up to 150 mbps).  In Win 8.1, using Comcast Speed  Test, I get download speeds of 100 +/- mbps.  In Ubuntu, I get 30 +/- mbps.  The cable is Cat5e, and I have tried many combinations of terminal commands, but unsuccessful in increasing downloads in Ubuntu.  Here is output from `lshw`:

```
~$ sudo lshw -numeric -C network -sanitize
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10EC:8168]
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. [10EC]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 11
       serial: [REMOVED]
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=[REMOVED] latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:89 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d0604000-d0604fff memory:d0600000-d0603fff
```

**EDIT 1:**

```
$ sudo ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: d
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                   drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
$ sudo ethtool -i eth0
driver: r8169
version: 2.3LK-NAPI
firmware-version: rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13
bus-info: 0000:02:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
```

**END EDIT 2**

Comment: Can you add the output of: `ethtool eth0`?

Comment: @Jeremy Kerr -- I added the information that you requested into the original post.

Comment: I know you mentioned it, but swapping my cable got me from 100 to 1000.

Comment: @Organic Marble -- In case I go that route (at the present, I don't know how that would explain the discrepancy), what cable did you install?

Comment: I just tried several that I had lying about.

Comment: Some Cat5e cables are more equal than others...

Comment: After further testing on my own, I found that one cable on mine would only do 100mb, then when I tried a different cable I hit Gigabit, and the speeds.  Make sure that you have a good Cat5e or better, and no kinks in the cable.

Answer (score 0):

NIC is now working at 1Gbps.  The problem was the cable between my computer and the Comcast modem, which is downstairs about 100' away, and next to my wife's computer.  My wife's Lenovo and my Acer download at 150 Mbps +/- when on a short cable connected directly from the modem (i.e., no intermediate plugs/sockets).  However, when my Acer is in the upstairs office, it is connected to the modem via cat5e that runs thru the walls, so there are 2 intermediate sets of wall sockets/plugs.  As a test, I got about 110' of new cat5e, installed the RJ45s at each end and strung the 110' down the halls and up the stairs.  With this cable between the modem and my Acer in the upstairs office, I now get 1Gbps speed.  Will now have to debug/upgrade the cabling in the walls.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: Update on my cabling in the walls.  Turns out that 4 of the cat5e wires were tied into the RJ45 and 4 were tied into the telephone jack!  Will have to run a new telephone line so the 8 wires in the cat5e can be dedicated to the internet.

Comment: I realize that you've probably already run whatever cable you need, but for anyone else with this issue: consider running CAT6 instead & leaving CAT5e as your telephone wire.